# display: none still effects placement of elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating my portfolio website responsive using media queries and I made a nav select drop down menu for the mobile screen. Now on the iPad screen I want to show a regular menu so I set the drop down menu display: none; in my CSS.

Now I noticed that although it doesn't show it is still selectable and causes my regular menu not to function proper because it is directly under it. Also my divs placed under the menu react to the dropdown menu like it is still there.

Why is it selectable and all? Hope someone can help me out!

Here is the code that is mainly important (I think)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<nav>

<ul>
<li><a href="camera.html">camera / editing</a></li>
<li><a href="interface.html">interface</a></li>
<li><a href="illustration.html">illustration</a></li>
<li><a href="drawing.html">drawing</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>
</div>

<nav> 
  <select>
    <option selected>Find my work here!</option>
    <option value="camera.html">Camera / Editing</option>
    <option value="interface.html">Interface</option>
    <option value="illustration.html">Illustration</option>
    <option value="drawing.html">Drawing</option>  
  </select> 
</nav>


    <div id="bio"><a href="#">About Me</a>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>

</div>
```

And the CSS

Mobile query

```
nav{
top: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: .7em;
height: 80px;
background: url("afb/top fade.png") top center no-repeat;
}

nav select{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
font-size: 1em;
opacity: 1;

}
```

iPad query

```
#menu{
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
}

nav{
    background-image: none;
    position: static;
}

nav select{
    display: none;
}

nav ul:first-of-type{
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

(people can check the full website at http://nickzijlstra.com/resp  just play with the browser size and you will see what happens)

Comment: Please include your media queries that activate those CSS styles. Also, you have an extra closing div in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code is hiding the dropdown nav > select, the nav and any associatied styling would still be present.

What about adding a class to the dropdown nav and hidding this as required?

```
<nav class="dropdown"> 
<select>
<option selected>Find my work here!</option>
<option value="camera.html">Camera / Editing</option>
<option value="interface.html">Interface</option>
<option value="illustration.html">Illustration</option>
<option value="drawing.html">Drawing</option>  
</select> 
</nav>
```

And for the iPad media query

```
.dropdown{
display:none;
}
```

Good luck!